# touchpad unglued

Tags: touchpad

The surface of the touchpad on my Sony Vaio Y has come unglued on one side.  It still works perfectly, but it's annoying.  Would it be safe to squirt a little glue underneath to stick it back down?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe a bit of double-sided tape or a very small amount of hotmelt glue (if poss) - I'd be concerned that any glue containing a solvent would attack the plastic/nearby casing - if you want to try though, look for 'low bloom' (super)glue - often sold in modelling shops for use on plastic models/RC cars etc.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  I glued it down using epoxy, applying it with a toothpick.  No apparent adverse effects yet.

Answer (score 0):

youhave to be vrey careful about it as glue could drip down and damage other parts and/or that end of your laptop might not  be responsive anymore  .
What I would suggest is that you find a wide enough sellotape(transparent scotch tape) that will cover the entire touch pad and tape it down.
Since its very thin there should be negligible sensitivity loss and you are in no danger of damaging any other component.